# Efficient use on network drive

Tags: networking

For some reason, everything in Mathematica is slower when working with a notebook that is stored on a network disk. In our company, there is typically no backup of the local C drive; all work is supposed to be on 'windows' shares (or sharepoint sites). But, when I store my notebook on my private network share, everything in Mathematica is slowed down. Most annoyingly, the tooltip that appears after entering the first two characters causes a noticeable delay. (On local disk everything is fast.) I can live perfectly with slow loads and saves, the notebooks and datasets are small.

Is there some configuration option that makes Mathematica more responsive, even when working interactively from a network drive?

How do people balance the need for efficient editing, execution and loading of notebooks with the need for backups or versioning?

Comment: The suggestion bar is notorious for causing delayed response (not tied to network issues though), so turning it of off in Preferences->Interface might help. I mostly work from networked drives, and apart from loading/saving I have experienced no other slow-downs to be attributed that...