# Why is listing files on a network share so slow? / How to speed it up?

Tags: performance-tuning, files-and-directories, windows, mac-os-x, system-performance

I'm using I need to load data in some files on a windows network share (samba), mounted on OSX. When listing the relevant directory in a shell, the performance is acceptable:

```
% time ls $DIR|wc -w
   26542
ls -G $DIR  0.05s user 0.33s system 98% cpu 0.376 total
wc -w  0.00s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 0.376 total
```

Compared to MMA:

```
In[36]:= fn = FileNames[All, dir]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[33]= {30.8174, Null}
```

Compared to local MMA (for the same dir):

```
In[36]:= fn = FileNames[All, dir]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[33]= {0.206, Null}
```

**Edit**

It seems that MMA is making an excessive amount of system calls since when listing the share mounted on (Windows 10) localhost is still very slow, though much faster:

```
In[36]:= fn = FileNames[All, dir]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[33]= {2.502, Null}
```

Comment: I am almost certain that something very similar was already asked (possibly years ago), but I can't seem to find it. You might want to search the site a bit more, maybe something comes up. Also: I would definitely report this to Wolfram.

Comment: This is the only related question I could find, unanswered: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108103/efficient-use-on-network-drive

Comment: Neither could I find anything remotely similar except for what @CarlLange linked.